# Cannot assign a value to final variable length

Tags: java

I have recently signed up to codewars. I was doing my first java kata, and I get a weird error on code that looks valid to me. Here is the code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Powers {
  public static BigInteger powers(int[] list) {
    BigInteger number;
    if (list.length = 0){
      number = 1;
    }else if (list.length = 1){
      number = 2;
    }else if (list.length > 1){
      number  = list.length * list.length;
    }
    return number;
  }
}
```

Here is the Stack Trace I get:

```
/Powers.java:6: error: cannot assign a value to final variable length
if (list.length = 0){
^
/Powers.java:6: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
if (list.length = 0){
^
/Powers.java:7: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger
number = 1;
^
/Powers.java:8: error: cannot assign a value to final variable length
}else if (list.length = 1){
^
/Powers.java:8: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
}else if (list.length = 1){
^
/Powers.java:9: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger
number = 2;
^
/Powers.java:11: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger
number = list.length * list.length;
^
7 errors
```

`java.lang.RuntimeException: /Powers.java:6: error: cannot assign a value to final variable length if (list.length = 0){ ^ /Powers.java:6: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean if (list.length = 0){ ^ /Powers.java:7: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger number = 1; ^ /Powers.java:8: error: cannot assign a value to final variable length }else if (list.length = 1){ ^ /Powers.java:8: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean }else if (list.length = 1){ ^ /Powers.java:9: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger number = 2; ^ /Powers.java:11: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BigInteger number = list.length * list.length; ^ 7 errors at codewars.runners.java$compile_and_load.doInvoke(java.clj:85) at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439) at codewars.runners.java$fn__572.invoke(java.clj:110) at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:227) at codewars.runners$run.invoke(runners.clj:22) at codewars.core$_main$fn__634.invoke(core.clj:40) at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Comment: If you have a new error, you should accept Tabaqui's answer, then ask a new question. Please do not change your existing question to address a different error than the one you originally asked about.

Comment: I removed the Clojure tag, because Clojure was only involved in the service running this, not in the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` here:

```
if (list.length = 0)
```

Comment: hey, it works!! Now I get the error that I am about to edit in.

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem If you have a new error, you should accept this answer, then ask a new question. Please do not change your existing question to address a different error than the one you originally asked about.

Comment: and also I would like to know the reason behind the down vote who ever it was.

Comment: BigInteger is not a primitive type: You can't assign literals directly or use the add/subtract/multiply(etc...) operators directly. You'll have to use the methods declared in the BigInteger class: add, valueOf, subtract etc... For example: number = BigInteger.valueOf(1); or number = BigInteger.valueOf(list.length).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(list.length));